# Julia--unrecognized subtype of nested unionall

Tags: julia

While writing a function with the following signature,

```
f(x::Vector{Tuple{Vector{<:Real}, Vector{<:Real}}})
```

I ran into an error I do not understand.  I tried calling this function `f` on `z`, defined as follows:

```
z = [([1,2], [3,4])]
```

(This is an array of tuples, where each tuple contains two arrays of real numbers; `z` as defined above only contains one such tuple.)

The type of `z` is

```
Array{Tuple{Array{Int64,1},Array{Float64,1}},1}
```

(as found by calling `typeof(z)`).  I had expected this to be a subtype of

```
Vector{Tuple{Vector{<:Real}, Vector{<:Real}}}
```

, the type in the function `f` above.

However, when I run the code

```
z::Vector{Tuple{Vector{<:Real}, Vector{<:Real}}}
```

I see the following error:

```
ERROR: TypeError: in typeassert, expected Array{Tuple{Array{#s6,1} where #s6<:Real,Array{#s5,1} where #s5<:Real},1}, gotArray{Tuple{Array{Int64,1},Array{Float64,1}},1}
```

Likewise, I get a method error when calling `f(z)`.  Why isn't `Array{Tuple{Array{Int64,1},Array{Int64,1}},1}` a subtype of `Vector{Tuple{Vector{<:Real}, Vector{<:Real}}}`?

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that:

```
julia> Tuple{Array{Int64,1},Array{Int64,1}} <: Tuple{Vector{<:Real}, Vector{<:Real}}
true
```

but clearly:

```
julia> Tuple{Array{Int64,1},Array{Int64,1}} >: Tuple{Vector{<:Real}, Vector{<:Real}}
false
```

and becasue types in Julia (except a `Tuple`, but here we have a `Vector`) are invariant (see [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/types/index.html#Parametric-Composite-Types-1)), you have that `Vector{S}` is not as subtype of `Vector{T}` even if `S <: T`.

so you need to write one additional subtyping qualification:

```
f(x::Vector{<:Tuple{Vector{<:Real}, Vector{<:Real}}})
```

and similarly:

```
julia> z::Vector{<:Tuple{Vector{<:Real}, Vector{<:Real}}}
1-element Array{Tuple{Array{Int64,1},Array{Int64,1}},1}:
 ([1, 2], [3, 4])
```

or extract the parameter using `where`:

```
julia> f2(x::Vector{Tuple{Vector{T}, Vector{T}}}) where {T<:Real} = x
f2 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> f2(z)
1-element Array{Tuple{Array{Int64,1},Array{Int64,1}},1}:
 ([1, 2], [3, 4])
```

or

```
julia> f3(x::Vector{Tuple{Vector{T}, Vector{S}}}) where {T<:Real, S<:Real} = x
f3 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> f3(z)
1-element Array{Tuple{Array{Int64,1},Array{Int64,1}},1}:
 ([1, 2], [3, 4])
```

(choose the first of second form against your decision if two elements of the tuple must have the same type or not)